# Python NaN squared error

Tags: python

This is purely out of curiosity, but why does this occur?

```
>>> a = float('Nan')
>>> a**2.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: (33, 'Domain error')
```

I would have expected it to simply return NaN instead of generating an error.

Comment: Python 2.5, 2.6, 2.7 won't raise an ValueError. What version are you using?

Comment: Ideone.com disagrees - http://ideone.com/sRWc9

Comment: What operating system?  What version of Python?  Please provide the OS  and Python details as an **update** to your question.

Comment: I got the same error. Python 2.6.5 on Windows 7 64 bits. But I get `nan` in my debian lenny with python 2.5

Comment: Sorry, should have included more details up front.  This is Windows XP with Python 2.6.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://www.mail-archive.com/relax-devel@gna.org/msg00337.html, it seems that this is only the case on the windows builds, due to how the compiler implements floating point stuff.

- Would some of the people who can't reproduce post their OS?
- Would someone having a 2.x on windows installed try it out (I get the same error on 3.1.3 (on Windows 7 32 bit))?
- @OP: You are using windows, yes?

---

Example

```
Python 2.6.2 (r262:71605, Apr 14 2009, 22:40:02) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> float('NaN')
nan
>>> _**2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: (33, 'Domain error')
```

Comment: see my answer, same compiler, different versions, different behaviour, odd

Comment: Yes, I am using windows with a slight older version of python 2.6.2.  I think you nailed it.  Thanks.

Comment: @Timothy: Not really. Seems that this isn't the answer, as some can't reproduce on windows either =/ The weirdest bugs are the worst, so this one is pretty bad...

Answer (score 4):

It looks like a bug in whatever implementation of Python you are using. It works as expected for me in all Python versions I tested, ranging from 2.5 to 3.1.

```
>>> nan = float('NaN')
>>> nan ** 2.0
nan
```

- [Python 2.6.4 on ideone](http://ideone.com/D6UgS)
- [Python 3.1.2 on ideone](http://ideone.com/NdM37)

Comment: That should be `**`, not `*`, but it works fine in 2.6.5, too.

Comment: (1) OP has that problem with `**`, not with `*`. (2) I have it too with 3.1.3

Comment: Same is true in my Python 2.4.6, 2.6.5, 2.6.6, 2.7.1, and 3.1.3.  @TimothyAWiseman, what version are you running, and on what platform?

Comment: @delnan: What do you mean by "I have it too"? Do you see the same error as the OP?

Comment: @Mark: Yes. See my answer for a possible explanation.

Answer (score 1):

On Vista SP2 Intel DualCore 2.1 GHz

CPython:

```
In []: sys.version
Out[]: '2.7.1 (r271:86832, Nov 27 2010, 18:30:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]'
In []: float('NaN')** 2.
Out[]: nan

>>> sys.version
'3.1.3 (r313:86834, Nov 27 2010, 18:30:53) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]'
>>> float('NaN')** 2.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: (33, 'Domain error')
```

Same compiler, but different versions, different results

From different world, IronPython:

```
>>> sys.version
'2.6.1 ()'
>>> float('NaN')** 2.
nan

>>> sys.version
'2.7.0 (IronPython 2.7 Beta 1 (2.7.0.10) on .NET 4.0.30319.1)'
>>> float('NaN')** 2.
nan
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I get

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:57:41) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2

>>> nan=float("NaN")
>>> nan
nan
>>> nan*2
nan
>>> nan**2
nan
>>>
```